# How can I query for vs code extension version during CI publish operation?

Tags: vscode-extensions

I am trying to use an automated build system that detects changes (feat/fix) and updates semver automatically ([repo-cooker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/repo-cooker)).

In order for this to work, I need to query the current "latest" version from the market place repository. Is there any proper way to do this without scraping the SVG badge (which seems safer than scraping a page) ?

```js
const got = require('got')
const RE = /<title>.*v([0-9\.]+)<\/title>/
const BASE_URL = 'https://vsmarketplacebadge.apphb.com/version-short'

async function getVersion(ext) {
  const response = await got(`${BASE_URL}/${ext}.svg`)
  const re = RE.exec(response.body)
  if (re) {
    return re[1]
  } else {
    throw new Error(`Could not scrape for ${ext} version.`)
  }
}

async function main() {
  console.log(await getVersion('pawijs.vscode-pawi'))
}

main()
```

Comment: FYI 'scrapping' (and 'scrap') means throwing away like rubbish. The correct terms are __scraping__ and __scrape__

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/vscode/comments/am1k1t/is_there_an_api_for_getting_list_of_all/ Use the undocumented Marketplace REST API.

Comment: @barny thanks for the typo fix. I don't think adding bold added any value to the question though.

Comment: @LexLi Thanks for the information but I think the public badge is safer than an internal undocumented api. I guess there is no official solution then...